# Accessing data from Datagrid with template columns

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have created a datagrid with `DataGridTemplateColumns`. I want to access the values of datagrid cells.
Here is my Xaml code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMappingColumns" Height="180" Width="450"  SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" PreparingCellForEdit="dgMappingColumns_PreparingCellForEdit">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CSVColumn">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtbDataColumn" Width="140" Text="{Binding DataColumn}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ExcelColumn">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbExcelColumn"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ExcelColumn}"
                            Width="220"
                                      SelectedItem="ExcelColumn"
                                      SelectionChanged="cmbExcelColumn_SelectionChanged"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Required">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbRequired"
                            ItemsSource=
                            "{Binding Required}"
                                      SelectedItem="Required"
                                      SelectionChanged="cmbRequired_SelectionChanged"
                           />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

and here is the code behind that I have tried to access value of each cell from datagrid.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < dgMappingColumns.Items.Count; i++)
        {

           TextBlock a = dgMappingColumns.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dgMappingColumns.Items[i]) as TextBlock;
            string aa = a.Text;

        }
```

Also I am binding list of the following class to datagrid for generating rows.
i.e.`public List<DataGridRowSet> DataGridRowSets { get; set; }`

```
public class DataGridRowSet
    {
        public string DataColumn { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> ExcelColumn { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Required { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan I want to access the value of each cell.

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am getting null value when trying to access the cell content from code behind.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where you are trying to get the TextBlock, and see what type of object is really being returned by GetCellContent(). If it's not a TextBlock, then trying to cast it to one (using `as TextBlock`) will return null, which might explain what your are seeing. I'm guessing `GetCellContent(...)` is returning some kind of "container" control used to render the cell, and your TextBlock will be somewhere in that.

Comment: @AndrewStephens: I did so. Its returning ContentPresenter and I am confused with that. I tried type casting it to textblock but it didn't work.

Comment: When WPF displays something like a grid cell, it creates a hierarchy of controls (e.g. the cell's border, background, highlighting, etc). Within this hierarchy it adds a `ContentPresenter` - a placeholder where the actual cell content will be rendered. When you get the ContentPresenter back, take a look at its `Content` property - is this your TextBox? (Also, I just noticed your XAML column template has a TextBox, but your code-behind is trying to cast to a TextBlock).